# Adding grouped mean values to column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I'd like to calculate group means in a data frame and create a new column in the original data frame containing those group mean values. (I'm doing a repeatability study and I want the mean value over measurements within an insertion, unit, and channel in a new column so I can subtract it off and calculate residuals.)

My data:

```
> head(mytestdata,15)
   Insertion Measurement Unit Channel Value
1          1           1   A5      10  9.41
2          1           1   A5      11  9.51
3          1           1   A5      12 10.59
4          1           1   A5      13  9.45
5          1           2   A5      10  9.42
6          1           2   A5      11  9.03
7          1           2   A5      12 10.62
8          1           2   A5      13  9.39
9          1           3   A5      10  9.38
10         1           3   A5      11  9.87
11         1           3   A5      12 11.34
12         1           3   A5      13  9.59
13         2           1   A5      10 12.10
14         2           1   A5      11 11.28
15         2           1   A5      12 12.95
```

Specifically, I want to calculate the mean Value per Insertion, Unit, and Channel, and add it to the data frame as meanValue. Then subtract meanValue from Value to get Residual.

Should look like this:

```
   Insertion Measurement Unit Channel Value meanValue
1          1           1   40      10 11.79     11.56
2          1           1   40      11 11.01     11.38
3          1           1   40      12 10.86     11.19
4          1           1   40      13 10.29     10.91
5          1           2   40      10 11.47     11.56
6          1           2   40      11 11.84     11.38
7          1           2   40      12 11.39     11.19
8          1           2   40      13 11.25     10.91
9          1           3   40      10 11.42     11.56
10         1           3   40      11 11.28     11.38
11         1           3   40      12 11.31     11.19
12         1           3   40      13 11.18     10.91
13         2           1   40      10 10.97     11.55
14         2           1   40      11 11.78     11.87
15         2           1   40      12 11.48     11.25
```

I know how to get the group means using by, aggregate, etc, which get me a second list or table with the values in it. I'm also confident I could get what I want using some convoluted looping procedures, but I'm looking to stuff them back in the same data frame in an elegant one- or two-line solution, and I figure there's got to be a way to do it but after days of searching I'm not finding it. I don't want a cumbersome solution because I want it to work well when I scale up to lots more data.

Comment: Roughly how large is your actual data, in terms of number of rows and columns?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ave` to calculate the groupmeans:

```
df$MeanValue <- with(df, ave(Value, Insertion, Unit, Channel, FUN = mean))
```

Then calculate the residuals:

```
df$Residual <- df$Value - df$MeanValue
df
#   Insertion Measurement Unit Channel Value MeanValue     Residual
#1          1           1   A5      10  9.41  9.403333  0.006666667
#2          1           1   A5      11  9.51  9.470000  0.040000000
#3          1           1   A5      12 10.59 10.850000 -0.260000000
#4          1           1   A5      13  9.45  9.476667 -0.026666667
#5          1           2   A5      10  9.42  9.403333  0.016666667
#6          1           2   A5      11  9.03  9.470000 -0.440000000
#7          1           2   A5      12 10.62 10.850000 -0.230000000
#8          1           2   A5      13  9.39  9.476667 -0.086666667
#9          1           3   A5      10  9.38  9.403333 -0.023333333
#10         1           3   A5      11  9.87  9.470000  0.400000000
#11         1           3   A5      12 11.34 10.850000  0.490000000
#12         1           3   A5      13  9.59  9.476667  0.113333333
#13         2           1   A5      10 12.10 12.100000  0.000000000
#14         2           1   A5      11 11.28 11.280000  0.000000000
#15         2           1   A5      12 12.95 12.950000  0.000000000
```

Or you could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Insertion, Unit, Channel) %>% mutate(MeanValue = mean(Value), Residual = Value - MeanValue)
```

Comment: First one could be written: `transform(df, MeanValue = ave(Value, Insertion, Unit, Channel))` .

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mytestdata)[, c("MeanValue", "Residual") := {m= mean(Value);list(m, Value-m)}, by=list(Insertion, Unit, Channel)]

mytestdata

#        Insertion Measurement Unit Channel Value MeanValue     Residual
#       1:         1           1   A5      10  9.41  9.403333  0.006666667
#       2:         1           1   A5      11  9.51  9.470000  0.040000000
#       3:         1           1   A5      12 10.59 10.850000 -0.260000000
#       4:         1           1   A5      13  9.45  9.476667 -0.026666667
#       5:         1           2   A5      10  9.42  9.403333  0.016666667
#       6:         1           2   A5      11  9.03  9.470000 -0.440000000
#       7:         1           2   A5      12 10.62 10.850000 -0.230000000
#       8:         1           2   A5      13  9.39  9.476667 -0.086666667
#       9:         1           3   A5      10  9.38  9.403333 -0.023333333
#      10:         1           3   A5      11  9.87  9.470000  0.400000000
#      11:         1           3   A5      12 11.34 10.850000  0.490000000
#      12:         1           3   A5      13  9.59  9.476667  0.113333333
#      13:         2           1   A5      10 12.10 12.100000  0.000000000
#      14:         2           1   A5      11 11.28 11.280000  0.000000000
#      15:         2           1   A5      12 12.95 12.950000  0.000000000
```

Comment: @Arun, Thanks, I did a microbenchmark, Seems like both dplyr and data.table are very close.  Any other faster variety?

Comment: On this data, any benchmark is really meaningless.. :). I'd try benchmarking on about 20 million rows, with different group sizes, say: a total of 1000 groups, 10,000, 100,000, a million groups.. You'll see where and how `data.table` scales!

Comment: akrun, [here you go](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/37a051c65275b58861fe). You can play around with it..

Comment: @Arun, thanks.  Looks like data.table beats dplyr in all the comparisons especially as groups gets bigger :-)

Comment: @akrun, how did you come up with this part: `{m= mean(Value);list(m, Value-m)}` is there some documentation you saw on it or thought of it yourself?

Comment: @David Arenburg, From an other solution of me where Arun edited.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought you can do that in `data.table`

Comment: @David Arenburg. There is another approach. `setDT(mytestdata)[,Mean.Value:=mean(Value), by=list(Insertion, Unit, Channel)][,Residual:=Value-Mean.Value]`

Comment: This one I'm familiar with. It is pretty straight forward and this is what I was using until now